# Created a React Native app but it looking good at 6 Inch screen but its not good at 4.3 inch

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, user-interface, react-native

I have developed a react native app by which its Ui usies react native elements library and uses  [react-native-size-matter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-size-matters) for elements resizing for different screen. So i changed all absolute values to react-size-matter values.

So, the Ui looks awesome in 5.5 inches and 6 + inches, but recently checked in 4.3 Inch screen, in this, the vertical dimensions are getting overflowed over the screen size.

Here is the pic of 4.3 Inch screen :

[image]

Check the bottom of the screen, as react-native-element button crosses the screen.

And but when testing in 6 inch screen ( i used this to create the app ), check the image the buttons are sitting at correct place.

What makes this issues ? As, i double checked the code every absolute value has been changed. but still i see this prob. Is this prob by react-native elements or my code ?

As , when i set the height to the card , its shrinking but the words and button is not shrinking. But all the contents are clubbed inside the card only.

Here is my entire code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { oneDayPlanSelected, monthlyPlanSelected } from '../../actions';
import { Text, Button, Card } from 'react-native-elements';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react- 
native-responsive-screen';
import { scale, verticalScale, moderateScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';
import { fontScale } from '../Scalling';

class PlanSelection extends Component {

onMonthlyPlanButtonPressed() {
    this.props.monthlyPlanSelected();
}

onOneDayPlanButtonPressed(){
    this.props.oneDayPlanSelected();
}

render () {

    const cowMilk = require('../../Images/cow_plan.png');
    const buffaloMilk = require('../../Images/buffalo_plan.png');

    return (
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>

            <View style={styles.topContainerStyle}>
                <View style={styles.topBlueBoxContainer}>

                    <Text h4 style={styles.introTextStyle}>
                        Now, Choose how you wish to buy ? We have two plans.
                    </Text>
                    <View style={styles.imageContainerStyle}>
                        <Image 
                            source={ this.props.milkType === 'Cow Milk' ? cowMilk : buffaloMilk }
                            style={styles.topContainerImageStyle}
                            resizeMode='contain'
                            resizeMethod='scale'
                        />
                        <View style={styles.choosePlanTextContainerStyle}>
                            <Text h4 style={styles.choosePlanTextStyle}>
                                Choose your plan.
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.noteContainerStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.noteTextStyle}>We are excited ! Kindly select any one plan, and note that Monthly plan has various sub plans. For more info kindly choose the plan. </Text>
            </View>

                </View>
            </View>

            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}>

                <View>
                    <Card
                    containerStyle={{borderRadius: 5, width: scale(150)}} 
                    >
                        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                <Text style={styles.planNumberTextStyle}>1</Text>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: fontScale(9.5), top: verticalScale(40), fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Day</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ paddingTop: verticalScale(2.5), paddingBottom: verticalScale(2.5), paddingLeft: scale(2.5), paddingLeft: scale(2.5) }}>
                            <Text style={styles.planDescpStyle}>Buy One day plan, by which we will deliver Cow Milk by Today.</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ paddingTop: verticalScale(13), paddingBottom: verticalScale(13), paddingLeft: scale(13), paddingLeft: scale(13) }}>
                            <Text style={styles.planNameTextStyle}>One Day Plan</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{  width: scale(120), }}>
                            <Button
                            backgroundColor='#2980b9'
                            rightIcon={{name: 'arrow-forward'}}
                            title='Buy'
                            raised
                            onPress={this.onOneDayPlanButtonPressed.bind(this)}
                            />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </Card>
                </View>

                <View>
                    <Card
                    containerStyle={{borderRadius: 5, width: scale(150) }} 
                    >
                        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                <Text style={styles.planNumberTextStyle}>30</Text>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: fontScale(9.5), top: verticalScale(40), fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Day's</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ paddingTop: verticalScale(2.5), paddingBottom: verticalScale(2.5), paddingLeft: scale(2.5), paddingLeft: scale(2.5) }}>
                                <Text style={styles.planDescpStyle}>We have various monthly plans, Check for more</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ paddingTop: verticalScale(13), paddingBottom: verticalScale(13), paddingLeft: scale(13), paddingLeft: scale(13) }}>
                                <Text style={styles.planNameTextStyle}>Monthly Plan</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ width: scale(120), flex: 1, }}>
                                <Button
                                backgroundColor='#2980b9'
                                rightIcon={{name: 'arrow-forward'}}
                                title='Buy'
                                raised
                                onPress={this.onMonthlyPlanButtonPressed.bind(this)}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>

                    </Card>
                </View>

            </View>

        </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = {

containerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    overflow: 'scroll'
},
topBlueBoxContainer:{
    backgroundColor: '#f0ffff',
    height: verticalScale(400),
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
},
imageContainerStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center'
},
topContainerImageStyle: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    height: verticalScale(230)
},
introTextStyle: {
    fontSize: fontScale(17.5),
    paddingLeft: scale(40),
},
choosePlanTextStyle: {
    fontSize: fontScale(20)
},
choosePlanTextContainerStyle:{
    alignSelf: 'center',
},
planNameTextStyle: {
    fontSize: fontScale(12),
    fontWeight: 'bold'
},
planNumberTextStyle: {
    fontSize: fontScale(50),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#37BBE1',
},
planDescpStyle: {
    fontSize: fontScale(12),
    textAlign: 'center'
},
noteTextStyle: {
    fontSize: fontScale(9),
    color: '#b2bec3'
},
noteContainerStyle: {
    paddingLeft: scale(12),
    paddingRight: scale(8),

}

};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    milkType: state.order.milktype
};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, 
{oneDayPlanSelected,monthlyPlanSelected})(PlanSelection);
```

Is my codes are correct ? I hope , i did everything correct as of now ! please guide if any mistakes in this. Expected solution, is that my ui should resize according to screen size.

[image]

Comment: How about trying native-base instead, to see if the problem is still there?

Comment: okay sure, will let you know once trying !